# Scraping an item that varies in position from a XML subpage

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

so far I didn't succeed in scraping the table "Die Verlustursache" from this page

```
http://www.ubootarchiv.de/ubootwiki/index.php/U_205
```

using libraries (XML) (rvest) (readr)

I can address all tables on the site with individual code lines like

```
table <-readHTMLTable("http://www.ubootarchiv.de/ubootwiki/index.php/U_203") %>% .[1]
```

but the numeric numbers vary on all the other sites.
check for example: http://www.ubootarchiv.de/ubootwiki/index.php/U_27

I just realized that the table I need is always the fourth last one (meaning: the last table minus 4).

In another scraping project, I once used this line to only scrape the last item of a list page:

```
html_nodes(xpath="/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[last()]"
```

However, I was not able to find a solution for something like "last - 4"

Please advise & Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this if it is always the fourth last table:

```
table <-readHTMLTable("http://www.ubootarchiv.de/ubootwiki/index.php/U_203") 


table[length(table) - 4]
```